# WordPress form with custom target on field choice

Tags: javascript, wordpress, forms, plugins, customization

I'm working on a website, on WordPress, and I need a form. The problem is I want to have a custom form for my needs :

```
>user select option (1,2,3...)
>if user select option 1, send form mail on submit to a
>if user select option 2, send form mail on submit to b
...
```

Is there a plugin that does that? Should I write a code or something for this? I have limited knowledge regarding scripts. This is why I'm coming here to find help. 
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Look for a form plugin that has conditional fields. WPForms (the paid version) does. You can ask them pre-sales questions.

Comment: Thanks, do you know any for free though? I found contact form 7, but the conditions are only for displaying informations if you pick something.